# Building and Compiling Error

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Im having a problem compiling my project, below is the screenshot of the error where am I having a problem, I tried adding the needed frameworks and used `CLEAN` function, but still not working.

[image]

Thanks for the help. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It is not able to find the Custom View ScratchableView that you are trying to access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that ScratchableView is not included in the link list.

- Press project-target in file list   (your APP project name in the file list)
- Targets set to: Photoslot      (your APP name)
- The Tab: Build Phases
- Open: Copy Bundle Resources
  Your file should be included here. If not press + to add. 
  When the file is listed in red, it is missing/wrong. Remove it (-) and add again

Answer (score 0):

You're encountering a referece error. Check your class OneSlotViewController.h/m for the include of ScratchableView.h which seems to be missing from your project. Another problem could be that ScratchableView class is not added to your target.

Comment: it says : `warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/ScratchableView.h' of type sourcecode.c.h for architecture i386`

Comment: try the steps form Vincent's response, it should definatly fix the issue if you do all the references/target dependencies right.